# Red folder in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm, there is a single folder in my Project window that is red.  What does that color mean when all the other folders are blue?  I have my project in Git and it is mostly Python with a Java GUI in the repo.

Comment: Apparently, you can mark a directory as excluded by right clicking on it and going to "Mark directory as..." > "Excluded"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those who have not marked their folder as "excluded", the color is due to merge conflicts.

A full list of file status colors can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html).